# Normalize [firefox] versioning tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

- [firefox-3](/questions/tagged/firefox-3) (85)
- [firefox-5](/questions/tagged/firefox-5) (36)
- [firefox-6](/questions/tagged/firefox-6) (1)
- [firefox-8](/questions/tagged/firefox-8) (2)

but

- [firefox2](/questions/tagged/firefox2) (12)
- [firefox3](/questions/tagged/firefox3) (1)
- [firefox3.5](/questions/tagged/firefox3.5) (40)
- [firefox3.6](/questions/tagged/firefox3.6) (111)
- [firefox4](/questions/tagged/firefox4) (203)
- [firefox6](/questions/tagged/firefox6) (21)

and so on!

I propose to use well-used dashed-form for versions.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that the non-hyphenated tags do not have synonyms defined, you could try doing this grass-roots style by tagging a few questions with the hyphen form, and then proposing the old tag as a synonym for the new tag.

Comment: I still don't know why, bit synonym proposition requires a number of upvotes in certain tag, what I don't have

Comment: @abat therefore you cannot do this entirely alone, but if others agree with you, it should be fairly simple to arrange, assuming my understanding of the process is correct.  I think you could even retag questions with existing upvotes to the new tag and have them count, but I am not sure.  Certainly you will need a few votes on the tag synonym, but indeed you *should* to prevent vandalism.